# scp with password and renaming the file

Tags: shell-script, rename, scp

I need to execute scp command with renaming the file.

I have tried with following code:

```
HOST=lnx25
USERNAME=ngqa
PASSWORD=xxxxx

FILE=$1
FILE_NAME=`echo $FILE | awk 'BEGIN{FS="/"} {print $NF;}'`

todayDateVar=`date | awk 'BEGIN{FS=" ";OFS="_"} {print $2,$3,$6;}'`
REPORT_HOME="/dnbusr1/ngqa/scp_script/new/"
DES_PATH="/ngdata/nc_donotdelete/test_out_files/$FILE_NAME.$todayDateVar"

scp $FILE $USERNAME:"$PASSWORD"@$HOST:sys_config $DES_PATH
```

Result: (Run with ./scp.sh sample.obj)

```
/ngdata/nc_donotdelete/test_out_files/sample.obj.Sep_23_2014: No such file or directory
```

I guess this error indicates none of directory available in that name.
But whenever i tried without renaming file means it works fine. The following code works fine without renaming the file.

```
DES_PATH="/ngdata/nc_donotdelete/test_out_files"
```

It copied the file name as sample.obj at destination directory.
But i need to copy the file with renaming.

Comment: What's that `sysconfig` doing in your scp? Right now, you're passing three parameters: `$FILE`, `$USERNAME…sys_config`, and thirdly `$DES_PATH`.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz I dont know exactly. had refered from Younes ERRATI answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451974/how-to-execute-a-scp-command-with-the-user-name-and-password-in-one-line

Comment: scp command sould be `scp $FILE $USERNAME:"$PASSWORD"@$HOST:$DES_PATH`

Comment: @Archemar If i change to `scp $FILE $USERNAME:"$PASSWORD"@$HOST:$DES_PATH` means i got `ssh: ngqa: Name or service not known
lost connection`

Comment: do you know you can login without a password using your public/private keys? Wouldn't it be better then having your login info stored in the script file?

Comment: About `todayDateVar`  It is unnecessary to use all that stuff.  You'd just  `todayDateVar=$(date +%b_%d_%Y)` at least if you want to achieve the same result. Also variable `FILE`.. what are you trying to do with it? Removing the slash?

Comment: @val0x00ff I will update for date as u specified. FILE_NAME for storing filename without the path.

Comment: @smrt28 Dont know.. pls Can u give link using public/private key...

Comment: @Vasu Then you'd need  `file="${1##*/}"`  Also don't use CAPITALS for var names.

Comment: ask google: "ssh public key authentication". Very first what google found was your answer: https://macnugget.org/projects/publickeys/. Or check the answer bellow which is also what you are searching for :-)

Answer (score 1):

If `DES_PATH="/ngdata/nc_donotdelete/test_out_files/$FILE_NAME.$todayDateVar"` doesn't work, and `DES_PATH="/ngdata/nc_donotdelete/test_out_files"` does, that means `/ngdata/nc_donotdelete/test_out_files` does not exist, and **your file is being saved as `/ngdata/nc_donotdelete/test_out_files` rather than `/ngdata/nc_donotdelete/test_out_files/$1`** (because the target path can be *either* a directory or a filename, and `scp` will treat it as a directory only if that path exists and is already a directory or link to a directory) You can add a slash to the end of the destination path to ensure that it is always treated as a directory rather than a file.

Answer (score 0):

plain password in file is a bad idea. Besides on my box I have no option `-p passwd`.

since you have access to remote host, you sould generate keys (private and public) using

```
ssh-keygen
```

(accept all default, do not use password)

This step should be done for every user

then, one time

```
ssh-copy-id ngqa@lnx25
```

This step should be done for every user and every host.

then in you shell, the last line sould be

```
scp $FILE $USERNAME@$HOST:$DEST_PATH
```